# Cannot override provider configuration

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Hi I have module(tf_module_vpc) where a provider is used, and its called on child(tf_module_eks_cluster)and then on root module to attach a transit_gatwarway attachment on nonprod account ( code is running on prod aws role)

I get the following error

> Error: Cannot override provider configuration

Pls point me what's this means and how can I fix this?

tf_module_vpc

--->main.tf
--->versions.tf

main.tf

```
// This resource only needs to be created when we are creating a cluster in prod.
//   Clusters in nonprod auto accept their own attachments since they're in the same account.
resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment_accepter" "prod_accepter" {
  count                         = local.do_transit_gateway_acceptance
  transit_gateway_attachment_id = aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment.ihm_gateway_attachment[count.index].id

  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      "Name" = var.vpc_name
      "Side" = "Accepter"
    },
  )

  provider = aws.transit_gateway

}
```

versions.tf

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.3.4"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source                = "hashicorp/aws"
      version               = "~> 4.40.0"
      configuration_aliases = [aws, aws.transit_gateway]
    }
  }
}
```

tf_module_eks_cluster

--> main.tf
--> providers.tf
--> versions.tf

main.tf

```
module "cluster_vpc" {
  source = "git@github.com:xx/tf_module_vpc.git?ref=xxx"
```

providers.tf

```
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "transit_gateway"
  region = var.region

}
```

versions.tf

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.3.4"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source                = "hashicorp/aws"
      configuration_aliases = [aws, aws.env, aws.ihrNonprod, aws.nonprod, aws.ops, aws.prod, aws.transit_gateway, ]
    }
  }
}
```

root-module

--> cluster.tf
--> providers.tf

cluster.tf

```
   module "cluster" {
      source = "git@github.com:xxxx/tf_module_eks_cluster.git?ref=vx.x"
    ...
     providers = {
        aws            = aws.prod
        aws.env        = aws.prod
        aws.nonprod    = aws.nonprod
        aws.ihrNonprod = aws.nonprod
        aws.ops        = aws.ops
        aws.prod       = aws.prod
        # Needed to access tgw in non prod account here:
        aws.transit_gateway = aws.nonprod
      }
```

providers.tf

```
# AWS creds for nonprod role
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "nonprod"
  region = "us-east-1"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::xxx"
  }
}

# AWS creds for ops role
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "ops"
  region = "us-east-1"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::xxx"
  }
}

# AWS creds for prod role
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "prod"
  region = "us-east-1"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::xxx"
  }
}
```

---

```
11:33:02 The Terraform configuration must be valid before initialization so that
11:33:02 Terraform can determine which modules and providers need to be installed.
11:33:02 ╷
11:33:02 │ Error: Cannot override provider configuration
11:33:02 │ 
11:33:02 │   on cluster.tf line 51, in module "cluster":
11:33:02 │   51:     aws.transit_gateway = aws.nonprod
11:33:02 │ 
11:33:02 │ The configuration of module.cluster has its own local configuration for
11:33:02 │ aws.transit_gateway, and so it cannot accept an overridden configuration
11:33:02 │ provided by the root module.
```

Answer (score 0):

In modern Terraform, only the root module (the one in the directory where you run `terraform apply`) should contain `provider` blocks. Other modules then receive provider configurations from their caller, either using the `providers` block explicitly or by implicit inheritance of default provider configurations.

However, as a concession to backward-compatibility with much older versions of Terraform, there remains *some* limited support for declaring provider configurations in non-root modules. When you use a module that uses that legacy feature, that replaces the ability to pass in the module from the caller.

In your case you are trying to use both the modern approach and the legacy approach at the same time, which is invalid. You can make this valid by removing the `provider "aws"` block from your non-root module, which will allow the provider configuration passed from the root module to be assigned in the `providers` map in your `module` block.